# Number of points on a surface modulo p

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, curves-and-surfaces

I am guessing that the number of solutions $(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_s)$ modulo $p$ of the system of polynomials
$$x_1x_2\cdots x_s=1,$$
$$(x_1-1)(x_2-1)\cdots (x_s-1)=u$$
where $u$ is non-zero modulo $p$.
Is it $$p^{s-2}+O(p^{s-3})$$ for $p\rightarrow \infty$?

Note: This is true for $s=4.$
Could someone give an idea on how to approach this question? Any reference or some help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/the-lang-weil-bound/

Comment: The Lang-Weil bound holds $p$ fixed and asymptotically counts points over $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$ as $e$ increases.

Comment: If $p=2$, the number is $0$.

Answer (score 11):

For $s \geq 6$ this is elementary as one can use the Weil bound for Jacobi sums, which predates Weil. By orthogonality of characters, we can express the number of points as $$ \frac{1}{ (p-1)^2} \sum_{\chi_1,\chi_2 \colon \mathbb F_p^\times \to \mathbb C^\times} \sum_{ x_1,\dots, x_s \in \mathbb F_p \setminus\{0,1\}}\chi_1( x_1 \dots x_s)  \chi_2 ( (x_1-1) \dots (x_s-1)) \overline{\chi_2(u)}$$

$$=  \frac{1}{ (p-1)^2} \sum_{\chi_1,\chi_2 \colon \mathbb F_p^\times \to \mathbb C^\times} \overline{\chi_2(u)} \left( \sum_{x\in \mathbb F_p \setminus \{0,1\}} \chi_1(x) \chi_2(x-1) \right)^s .$$

Now the inner sum over $x$ is $p-1$ if $\chi_1=\chi_2=1$ and otherwise has absolute value at most $\sqrt{p}$. More precisely, it has size exactly $\sqrt{p}$ unless $\chi_1=1, \chi_2=1$, or $\chi_1\chi_2=1$ and in any of these three cases (but not all of them) it has size $1$. This is the classical estimate for Jacobi sums. So the number of points is $(p-1)^{s-2}$ plus an error term of size bounded by $ \frac{p^2-2p}{ (p-1)^2} p^{s/2} \leq p^{s/2}$ which is $O(p^{s-3})$ as soon as $s\geq 6$, and furthermore the main term $(p-1)^{s-2}$ of course differs from your stated main term $p^{s-2}$ by $O(p^{s-3})$.

You have already handled the case $s=4$. The answer is pretty clearly negative for $s=2$ and it's probably possible to check the answer is negative for $s=3$. This leaves only the case $s=5$.

To handle this case, we just need an improvement of $\sqrt{p}$ in the error term. This can be done using Katz's theory of hypergeometric sheaves: For fixed $\chi_1 \neq 1$, the sum over $\chi_2$ is a finite field hypergeometric function of $u$, and Katz's estimates for such functions imply that we can strengthen the error term to something like $ \frac{1}{p-1} sp^{(s+1 )/2} + \frac{1}{p-1} = O ( p^{(s-1)/2})$